# Series involving someone who looked young, but was actually old, a magical barrier to the north, and a sarcophagus

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to find the name of a series. I read the first two books but the third wasn't finished at that time — it probably is by now — but I can't remember the name of the series, the author, or the title of any of the books. It must be fairly recent, within the last 5 years, give-or-take.

I can't quite remember enough to give a coherent account, apologies for that. Here is what I can recall:

- One character looked young but was very old or a reincarnation.
- There was some sort of magical barrier in the north, some characters
  got trapped on the wrong side.
- There was some sort of sarcophagus designed to cause pain for someone that couldn't die - possibly the first character I mentioned was placed in it, or placed someone into it.
- The story began, I think, with a flashback to the character (or his previous incarnation) defying someone (a mentor?) and throwing himself into a pool, or vortex

I'm afraid that's it. Hopefully this is all from one series and I'm not conflating different stories. Does this ring a bell with anyone?

Comment: The story began, i think, with a flashback to the character (or his previous incarnation) defying someone (a mentor?) and throwing himself into a pool, or vortex.

Comment: Hmm... did the early bit involve fire and ice opposing each other, with the guy who threw himself in the vortex being frozen in the ice? And there's a brother and a sister, with the sister winding up in the sarcophagus, emerging with powers due to it actually being a technology-based stasis chamber? One character is a weak boy who is actually the son of the main villain, might have been compelled to go to his father at some point, resulting in him getting hurt when he tries to walk past a gang of bandits?

Comment: Gosh darn it... I'm having trouble placing this one. I read it several years ago, I think after seeing it pop up on this site. The bit about the sarcophagus is part of what is ringing out in my head, that and referring to the "vortex" at the beginning. If so, the sarcophagus was actually being run by AIs who were thought to be demons, or fae. There was something with the brother and sister getting split up due to the ship they're on getting hit by a storm.

Comment: @Fuzzyboots That must be from a different but similar book to OP.  Those details dont match the Licanius Trilogy that well.

Comment: @JMac: I've created my own question. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like [The Licanius Trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22878967-the-shadow-of-what-was-lost) by James Islington. The books are, The Shadow of What Was Lost, An Echo of Things to Come and The Light of All That Falls.

There is indeed a barrier in the north behind which the main character Davian and two companions get trapped when another companion is put in a device that drains her power (the sarcophagus) and powers the barrier. The sarcophagus also creates a magical virtual reality to make being in the sarcophagus bearable.

The beginning of the book has one of the other main chracters (who is immortal) throws himself into a vortex, escaping his old master.

Comment: Thank you! Thats been driving me up the wall.